# Refused entry to UK on Eurostar from Paris: how long can I stay in Paris?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, schengen-visas

My partner was refused entry from Paris to London via Eurostar. After being interviewed and refused we were taken back to the French police immigration.

We asked how long does she have until she needs to leave Paris, the police officer said she has 3 months.

We were confused as she has been in Paris nearly 3 months, but I guess it kind of makes sense as she left France and got stamped out, got refused at the UK part, then entered back in.

She has a new stamp with the date but it has the cross/2 lines on the stamp.

She was planning to stay another 2 months then go home, but now we are unsure and do not want to stay here illegally.

The officer said 3 months, bu8t maybe he wasn't aware she had been here nearly 3 months previously? Or because she reentered and got stamped, she now has a new 3 months, even though it has the cross?

Comment: What is your partner’s citizenship?

Comment: @HankyPanky I think it is more likely that the officer failed to count the previous visit. Why would the failed attempt to go to the UK change the 90/180 rule? A clock reset would make more sense in the reverse direction (entry to France refused in London), since the UK rule is per-admission and not cumulative.

Comment: Without knowing your partner's citizenship and what kind of visa she has, I don't think this question can be answered. I'm voting to close for now but this isn't permanent. If you edit to include the necessary information, the question will be reopened (or the close process cancelled if it hasn't got that far).

Comment: I think it is safe to make plans to leave France before the 90 days of the first visit are up, if you do get the extra days you can still leave early. But if you stay over that 90 days period and it turns out that the officer did miss your earlier stay you will have an overstay against you and those can ruin a lot of plans for future travel.

Comment: It likely doesn't matter, but what is your citizenship? Are you and your partner in a long-term, cohabitating relationship?

Answer (score 6):

No matter what kind of Schengen visa (or visa-free 'allowance') your partner has, a trip to London will not reset any counter, only interrupt it for the time you spend outside the Schengen area. Since you exited the Schengen area and were readmitted on the same day, your partner will still have to obey to the same time limits, as if you hadn't left the Schengen area at all.

Since you are several times mentioning three months (although you probably mean 90 days) and was 'stamped in', I assume that your partner is from a visa-excempt non-EEA country or has a type C visa with default restrictions. In both cases, your partner can stay in the Schengen area for 90 days within any 180 days period and *not* 90 days after each entry. If your partner spent at least 90 days outside the Schengen area prior to the last entry, he/she must leave the Schengen area before 90 days after the last entry (the entry 'nearly three months ago').

Comment: I would add that France does not allow Schengen visa extensions, except in rare circumstances. It is not the case of all Schengen area countries.

Comment: @gstorto With very few exceptions, the only way for a non-EEA citizen to stay more than 90 days in the Schengen area is to get a national type D visa. There is no way to extend a type C visa to be valid for visits longer than 90 days. If it is possible to apply for a type D visa when already there, or if the application has to be made in your home country depends on national law. It is in any case nothing an immigration officer can decide upon at the border.